# Geometry Nodes - How to procedurally generate new points on a mesh relative to an empty?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

[image: Plants go bye-bye.]

I have an empty linked to a Displacement Modifier with a Musgrave Texture to procedurally generate hills - nothing special. Plenty of tutorials on that.

I can get my plants to move on the terrain with the empty, but I can't figure out how to get new ones to generate and remove those that go out-of-bounds. I thought of a few workarounds, like using a Shrinkwrap Modifier to project a large subdivided plane on top and removing the edges with a Boolean modifier (which does the job), but they're WAY too system-intensive.

Basically, I want my plants to come and go just like the hills, primarily utilizing geometry nodes (if possible). Also if anyone knows how to prevent these points from jumping around without massive amounts of subdivision, that information would be much appreciated.

Comment: He's only doing it with one object, but take a look at [this YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/F2NcNJQZFqw) for a good way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I already watched this video, and while creating the terrain fully in Geometry Nodes is probably the way to go, I'm sticking with the default material generator for the time being as I'm far more familiar with that. Plus I already fine-tuned my terrain and didn't want to redo everything.

Comment: I was thinking more about how he used raycasting to position the plane but I now realize you want the objects to do more than sit on the terrain, you want them to scroll with it.  Sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only cheap idea i have is making a "normal" distribution on a "long" plane and then delete it between the coordinates...so it looks like this:

[image]

i realized the "deletion" like this:

[image]

Comment: Well I'll be! This is perfect! Limiting the draw distance with a Delete Geometry Node keeps excess terrain from loading in, and the Set Position Node translates that Geometry without moving the origin, allowing the trees on top to move with it! Thank you so much!

Comment: The only thing I left out was the Realize Instances Node. I made the terrain with Modifiers, then used Geometry Nodes to limit the size of the square and generate plants. That way all the plants remain as instances and save me hundreds of thousands of polys, reducing lag. Thanks again!